# How do I copy the active sheet and attach it to an email without its folder name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to attach the active sheet as an attachment in an email.
That part i managed but the way I do it requires the forldername to be in the filename.

This is what I have

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim FileName As String
Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Sheets("X").Copy
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
FileName = "SCHEDULE"
On Error Resume Next
Kill folderPath & FileName
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
WB.SaveAs FileName:=folderPath & FileName


.Attachments.Add WB.FullName

WB.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
Kill WB.FullName
WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

The desired result is attaching the excel file with only the FileName

Answer (score 0):

FolderPath & FileName currently don't have a backslash in between them. You should use:

```
Kill folderPath & Application.PathSeparator & FileName
```

Similarly in the save operation:

```
WB.SaveAs FileName:=folderPath & Application.PathSeparator & FileName
```

You also seem to have a missing object (an e-mail object?) in the following line:

```
.Attachments.Add WB.FullName
```

Comment: It now attaches the file correcty (without the folder name) I tgives an `FIle not found` error though on the following line `Kill folderPath & Application.PathSeparator & FileName`

Comment: Double check that you still have error handling before & after that Kill line, as per your posted code. With an `On Error Goto 0` statement, any missing file errors should be suppressed.